# Detect iOS 8 Quicktype suggestion paste

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, ios8, contenteditable

For rich text editing I have a UIWebView where I load a local html content with some `contenteditable` div.
When user is pressing some keys on keyboard I want to detect content changes within that div, resize it accordingly and scroll properly to position cursor above the keyboard.

I'm able to do this using `onkeyup` event handler:

`<div id="contents" onkeyup="keyup()" onpaste="paste()" contenteditable="true">...</div>`

In iOS 8 keyboard now has the Quicktype panel with some suggestion words to quickly paste into editable area. How to detect the action of pasting the suggestion text into div?

Event handler like `onkeyup` doesn't help as the text is pasted without pressing keyboard buttons, `onpaste` event is not get called.
I also tried to implement [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/2797141) to detect DOM changes when something is pasted - doesn't help too.

I'm struggling trying to find the working solution. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Mobile Safari the iOS 8 Quicktype words fire two (maybe identical?) `input` events.

Try this in the developer console:

```
$('input[type=text]').on("input", console.log.bind(console, "input!"));
```

In UIWebView I have not tried...